# tcolorbox: How to enforce inner sep at tcolorbox raster?

Tags: tcolorbox

I set `left=5pt, right=5pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt` for the *inner sep* of a tcolorbox raster.

He tries to set the boxes height on the highest box - that's ok and wanted.

He also tries to set the raster across the entire text width - that's ok too - but he substitutes the ***inner xsep*** in the box / column with the content "X". 
***How can I force in that box that the settings `left=5pt, right=5pt` are set?***

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
raster equal height=rows, 
raster columns=3,
halign=left, valign=top, 
% This is the point =========================
left=5pt, right=5pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt,
% ===================================
]
\tcbitem \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center] \Huge X
\tcbitem \lipsum[63]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `tcbraster` equally divides its total width (`linewidth` by default) between its columns. This is the reason for your wider than expected central box.

You can force the width for a particular box with `raster force size=false` and some `add to width` on a particular box. But in this case you have to manually compute all widths in order to distribute the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
raster equal height=rows, 
raster columns=3,
halign=left, valign=top, 
% This is the point =========================
left=5pt, right=5pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt,
% ===================================
raster force size=false
]
\tcbitem \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center] \Huge X
\tcbitem \lipsum[65]


\tcbitem \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center, add to width = -3cm] \Huge X
\tcbitem \lipsum[65]

\tcbitem[add to width=1.5cm] \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center, add to width = -3cm] \Huge X
\tcbitem[add to width=1.5cm] \lipsum[65]

\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution to have different width columns could be the `raster multicolumn` option. In this case you define a default large number of columns (9 in following example) but group in three visible boxes where first and third has a width equivalent to four initial boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
raster equal height=rows, 
raster columns=9,
halign=left, valign=top, 
% This is the point =========================
left=5pt, right=5pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt,
% ===================================
%raster force size=false
]
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center] \Huge X
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[65]


\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center] \Huge X
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[65]

\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[66]
\tcbitem[colframe=red, halign=center, valign=center] \Huge X
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] \lipsum[65]

\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case, width `tcbraster` you cannot expect that boxes adapt the width to its contents (and respect inner margins) because their size is defined by the raster width and the columns number and not by their contents.

Comment: TYVM, helps me good! :)